# Perform ls command with * in name

Tags: ruby, ls

I would like to perform an ls command on a file named like /var/local/tmp/foo*.  I have been trying to use

```
%x[ls "#{path]"]
```

but this returns:

```
ls: /var/local/tmp/foo*: No such file or directory
```

Note that %x[ls '/var/local/tmp/foo*'] also returns above error.

If I do the same command, but as follows:

```
%x[ls /var/local/tmp/foo*]
```

it works correctly.

I am guessing that putting the directory path into a string is causing ls to treat it as a file literally named "/var/local/tmp/foo*".

Any ideas how to get around this?  I would like to use a variable that holds this string, so just putting in /var/local/tmp/foo* directly is not an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like `"/path/to/*"` is called a *glob*, and they are actually expanded by *the shell*, not by commands like `ls`. While you could run the shell to have it expand the glob for you, it is easier to just use the built-in [`Dir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html) class.

```
Dir["/path/to/*.txt"]
```

This returns an array of matching file names.